# How can I set session variable with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

By using below code on button click I get the href attribute value, until this everything is fine but when I got my `href` link on button click we want to store it in the session variable (i.e. var `href`) because we also use this variable elsewhere. Please suggest me how to store JavaScript variable in session.?

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.button').click(function(){
                var href = $(this).val();
                alert(href);
            })
        });
    </script>
<button value="<?php echo $value['3']; ?>" class="button" style="background-color:#ff8c21;">Buy Now</button>
```

Comment: use ajax to send the value to a php script that will process it specifically

Comment: Sessions live on the server not the browser. There is no direct link from js to the session. You would have to get js to send data to a php script on the server using AJAX so the PHP could amend your session variables

Comment: If you want to use on same without reload, you can bind this value to window, else you have to use ajax. Cookies might be an alternative depending upon your data

Comment: I want to use on same without reload, can you explain in brief by using ajax how to send value to the php script.

Comment: i explain in my answer how to use ajax to send value to php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try it if you want to use session using jquery
First include jquery-1.9.1.js and jquery.session.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.button').click(function(){
        var href = $(this).val();
        $.session.set("yoursessioname", "storevalue");
    }) 
});
alert($.session.get("yoursessioname"));
```

more detail http://phprocks.letsnurture.com/create-session-with-jquery/

Comment: Please edit your answers to have proper formatting. Several of your answers just dump code as text, are code-only, or do not properly format code.

Comment: By adding "jquery.session.js" into our page we can easily store value in session variable then how can we echos in some other page for testing point of you

Comment: by using document.write($.session.get('linkurl')); we will get value in other page also but this value is not same as actually we get on button click value.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set **SESSION WITH JAVASCRIPT** this is because its server side functionality so if you want to use this `data` some where else you can send a ajax request to server and there you can create session for this data.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.button').click(function(){
                var href = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,//url to file
                    data: {val:href},
                    success: function(data){
                    //success
                      };

                    });
                 });
              });
```

PHP:

```
 session_start();
 if(isset($_POST['val']))
 {
  $_SESSION['href'] = $_POST['val'];//created a session named "href"
 }
//use session 
if(isset($_SESSION['href']))
{
echo $_SESSION['href'];//use your session.
}
```

Comment: I open php file and I see `undefined index`

Comment: `undefined index val` ?

Comment: yep because you don't check if it exists or is set

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store it in session which is SERVER side then you need use ajax pass variable and store it in php for example with

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 !isset($_POST['var']) ?: $_SESSION['var'] = $_POST['var'];
```

but you can think of using cookies as well, then you don't need PHP it can be done only with JavaScript. There is nice [Jquery plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#readme) for that

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript works in the browser and PHP sessions are activated on the server, so you can't change session variables without sending a request to the server eg via a url or by submitting a form.
BUT you could use sessionStorage, which is a similar principle but lives in the browser and is modifiable by javascript.

eg. (inside javascript)

```
sessionStorage.myvariable=myVal
```

etc. It will live as long as your tab is open (from page to page).